# Is the a way to cancel/not list directories/files which can't be read anyways because of lacking permission by fs.readdirSync?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

A way to filter out those directories which need administration permission.

```
fs.readdirSync(currentPath, { withFileTypes: true }).forEach(element => {
   ....
})
```

Still shows all directories. Even those that need admin permission to be read/written to etc.

Comment: No, get the stats of each file individually. Or even better, just try to read them, then ignore them when you get a permission error - that's the only proper way to avoid race conditions, since permissions can change.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the  [`fs.access()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsaccesspath-mode-callback) method:

> Tests a user's permissions for the file or directory specified by path

```
// Check if you have permission to read the file
function isFileReadable(file) {
  try {
    fs.accessSync(file, fs.constants.R_OK);
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}

fs.readdirSync(currentPath, { withFileTypes: true }).forEach(element => {
    // If the file is readable, log it
    if(isFileReadable(element)) {
      console.log(`${element}`);
    }
   ...
})
```